# Using XSLT to check the value of the specific attribute and update the text

Tags: xml, xslt

The input xml is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<advert>
        <adKey>20151014001</adKey>
        <adStatus>REPEAT</adStatus>
        <adLabelInformation/>
        <formatInformation shape="Horizontal">1/2 TAB</formatInformation> 
        <adPositioningInformation/>
</advert>
```

Expected XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<advert>
            <adKey>20151014001</adKey>
            <adStatus>REPEAT</adStatus>
            <adLabelInformation/>
            <formatInformation shape="Tab_H">RHP1/2</formatInformation> 
            <adPositioningInformation/>
</advert>
```

Check the text and shape attribute in formatInformation, if suppose formatInformation has text "1/2 TAB" and has shape attribute "Horizontal" change the shape attribute value as "Tab_H" and text as "RHP1/2" using XSLT

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hey @maria - what is the question and/or issue you're facing? Please update your post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="advert">
         <xsl:choose>
             <xsl:when test="./formatInformation[@shape='Horizontal']='1/2 TAB'">
                 <advert>
                     <adKey><xsl:value-of select="./adKey"/></adKey>
                     <adStatus><xsl:value-of select="./adStatus"/></adStatus>
                     <adLabelInformation><xsl:value-of select="./adLabelInformation"/></adLabelInformation>
                     <formatInformation shape="Tab_H"><xsl:value-of select="'RHP1/2'"/></formatInformation>
                     <adPositioningInformation><xsl:value-of select="./adPositioningInformation"/></adPositioningInformation>
                 </advert>
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
                 <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
             </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```